# check is a string contains another string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to check if a string contains another string as a full word. E.g.: on the following example the code should only return something if the full word is found LOUIS XI should not be returned because the text contains LOUIS XIV

My code:

```
str1="Louis XI"
str2="Louis X, Louis XIII and Louis XIV were great kings"

if str2.find(str1) != -1:
    print('True')
```

I get True instead of False because Louis XI is not Louis XIII. How can I improve my code ?

Comment: Maybe by putting`if str2.find(f' {str1} ')` but it will work only with space boundaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expressions with a word boundary (`\b`):

```
import re

str1 = "Louis XI"
pattern = re.compile(fr"\b{str1}\b")

str2 = "Louis X, Louis XIII and Louis XIV were great kings"
str3 = "Louis X, Louis XI, and Louis FooBar"

print(bool(re.search(pattern, str2)))
print(bool(re.search(pattern, str3)))
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> False
> True
> ```

Comment: How can I edit ```re.compile(r"\bLouis XI\b")``` if I want to try multiple str like Louis XIII, Louis XIV, ... ?

Comment: @ayansalt, Does my edited answer provide an answer for that? Now it always uses `str1` as the one to test.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @ruohola Thats exactly what I wanted :)